# Grails with MongoDb and MapReduce

Tags: grails, mongodb

Does the [MongoDB GORM](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) Grails plugin support MapReduce and how can I use it? I've been looking in the documentation but seen no mention of it.

The [Gmongo](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo) plugin supports MapReduce but I find the documentation somewhat lacking. How can I supply a finalize function and set output to `inline`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GMongo is just a thin wrapper around the standard Java MongoDB API, the reference for Map/Reduce is here:

http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#mapReduce(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.mongodb.MapReduceCommand.OutputType,%20com.mongodb.DBObject)

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

You can just do:

`Book.collection.mapReduce(...)`

Answer (score 1):

In gmongo use something like this for accessing finalize function. First define the string of map, reduce and finalize somewhere above the following code and then call the following code:

```
    MapReduceCommand mapReduceCommand = new MapReduceCommand(coll, map, reduce, null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null)
    mapReduceCommand.setFinalize(finalize)
    def result = coll.mapReduce(mapReduceCommand)
```

Here, coll is an object of the collcetion Eg:

```
    DBCollection coll = db.<your_collection_name>
```